# How to show image and description in Categories widget in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hello friends i want so image and description in categories list widget for showing description i use below code:

in function.php

```
function wpb_catlist_desc() {
    $string = '<ul>';
    $catlist = get_terms( 'category' );
    if ( ! empty( $catlist ) ) {
      foreach ( $catlist as $key => $item ) {
         $string .= '<li>'. $item->name . '<br />';
         $string .= '<em>'. $item->description . '</em> </li>';
      }
   }
$string .= '</ul>';

return $string; 
}
add_shortcode('wpb_categories', 'wpb_catlist_desc');
```

and in class-wp-widget-categories.php

```
echo do_shortcode('[wpb_categories]');
```

it is showing categories name and his description now i want to show categories image also. any one please help me how can i get that. i had try Categories Images plugin for show images but can't able to show

Comment: Categories Images plugin name and link send

Comment: http://zahlan.net/blog/2012/06/categories-images/

this is the link of plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image get `z_taxonomy_image_url($id)` and `z_taxonomy_image($id)`

```
if(z_taxonomy_image_url($item->term_id))
{
    $string .= '<img src ="'.z_taxonomy_image_url($item->term_id).'" style="width: 20%;">';
}
```

Comment: working but if image does not selected it showing blank path

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image using following code and append it to $string.

```
 $catlist = get_terms( 'category' ); // get category list
 $string ="<ul>";
 foreach ( $catlist as $key => $item ) 
 {
   $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $item->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
    if ( $image ) {
        $image_dis='<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $cat->name . '" />';
    }

  $string .= '<li>'. $item->name . '<br />';
  $string .=  $image_dis . '<br />';
  $string .= '<em>'. $item->description . '</em> </li>';
}

$string .="</ul>";

echo $string;
```